# Reading file data with scanner, how to check if field is empty

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream, printwriter

I have this file

```
@ARTICLE{
8249726, 
author={N. Khlif and A. Masmoudi and F. Kammoun and N. Masmoudi}, 
journal={}, 
title={Secure chaotic dual encryption scheme for H.264/AVC video conferencing protection}, 
number={1}, 
year={2018}, 
volume={12}, 
pages={42-52},
```

I am using a scanner to read. I want to find out if a file is invalid by seeing if one of the brackets {} is empty, example above journal has no information therefore it would be invalid.
I tried using sc.next(); etc charat() thought of using split but there are no whitespaces....
Not sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: If this were my task, I'd write code to parse a basic line of text -- `text={stuff-in-brackets}` first. I'd then test if the String obtained from within the brackets, let's call it `value` is empty --`if (value.trim().isEmpty()) {...}`

Comment: But you're not showing us *how*  you are parsing this data, which makes it hard for us to suggest a solution to your problem without writing all your code for you.

Comment: hey, right now im just doing while( hasnextline()) and reading through the file, trying to store data into string etc... this is quite new for me, i will look into parsing the data, i did not know i could do what you showed above.

Comment: OK, yes, you get a line, then you should pass that line of text to a method that parses, that extracts the information on the left of the `=` into a field, say called `key`, and the right part within the `{}` into another field, say called `value`, and then create a KeyValue object out of it. You need to first write code to do this, and only then, look at how to test if `value` holds an empty String. You look to be here too early.

Comment: thank you, i appreciate the help,  ive just been stuck on this part for over 3hours now and i needed a direction to spend my time more efficiently.

Comment: I would further use a state-machine to help you solve this. If your text file contains many similar blocks of text, all representing a different article, then parse each *section* building an Article object in the process. Each Article likely has fields corresponding to the keys in your key-value pairs above. The parser would be in `getArticle` state, followed by `getKeyValue` state, followed by `finishArticle` state for each article found.

Comment: Assuming you create a class called `KeyValuePair`, then you would call `KeyValuePair pair = parseKeyValue(line);` a method which would contain code that would extract the information on the line and create a KeyValuePair object from the text. Once obtained, you would do `String key = pair.getKey();` which should return "journal" and likewise `String value = pair.getValue();`. You could test `if (value.isEmpty()) {...}` and act accordingly